# Check if a json value match a number with leading zero and convert it to a string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a Json file exported from PhpMyAdmin. I need to convert it to a javascript object or even better to a javascript array. I'm using **Nodejs module** `fs.readFile()` to read the file and `Json.parse()` function to convert the string to an object, but this function hang when it finds a number with leading zero. I need to convert the number to a string. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

here is the content of a json file exported directly from PhpMyadmin:

```
[{"id": 1,"country": 0,"code":056897,"customer":"Joe Harris"},{"id": 2,"country": 2,"code":054597,"customer":"Frank Foe"}]
```

I want to convert it in a Javascript object with node:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var docs  = fs.readFile('dbfiles/countries.json','utf8', function (err, data) {

 if (err) throw err;

 //code needed here to convert numbers with leading zero in string


 var docsJsonData = JSON.parse(data);

 });
```

Comment: Can you please add an example ?

Comment: @blunderboy sure here we go

Comment: Thanks for adding the example. That's not valid JSON unfortunately.

Comment: Added an OK workaround as an answer given that the `parse` function completely chokes on the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you could cause phpMyAdmin to emit valid JSON, that would be the best choice.

However, you could do some reasonable custom fixups using regular expressions. For example, the example you gave:

```
// data is from the file 
// match on "code":0####
var fixCode = /"code":(0[0-9]+),/g;
var results = JSON.parse(
    data.replace(fixCode, function(match, code) { 
        // rebuild the "code" property with quotes 
        // (or convert to a VALID number):
        return '"code": "' + code + '", '; 
}));
```

Results:

```
[ { id: 1,
    country: 0,
    code: '056897',
    customer: 'Joe Harris' },
  { id: 2,
    country: 2,
    code: '054597',
    customer: 'Frank Foe' } ]
```

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't able to export the file in a proper json format, anyway thanks for your code, your solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't allow leading zeros in number see [rfc4267](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) section 2.4. That is, if you have a number with leading zero, it's not proper JSON.

If you really need to parse this file, you can prepend it with something like `exports =`, but there is no guarantee that this will work as expected, since javascript may treat leading zero as a sign of octal number, if no digits more than 7 are used: e.g. `017 === 15`, but `018 === 18`

Answer (score 0):

I know it may seem weird but the quickest solution I often use to convert a number to a string is, `str = num+''`.

Here some other cases and perfs
http://jsperf.com/scunliffe-number-to-string

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether this will help you, but for converting the string containing an integer with leading zeros, you can use this:

```
var x = parseInt("00001000",10);
```

...which will correctly put 1000 as an integer value into x.